# sitting position... knees open or what?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

[image]

Image cropped from https://yurielkaim.com/7-fat-burning-leg-exercises/

---

I am making a sentence presenting the image in picture. I want to say that one shouldn't sit the way that the knees are wide open. Does this construction suits best? Note the bottom of the man should be resting on the floor, it's not in the image though. Actually I couldn't find one. I just want to present the position of the knees.

---

You should not sit in a way that knees remain open.

Comment: This picture appears to show a weight-lifter performing an exercise, not a person who is sitting down.

Answer (score 4):

That image is of someone squatting, and I'm glad you aren't saying "do that but with your knees together", because it would be very difficult.

We usually describe knees as being ***apart*** or ***together***, rather than open and closed. So you might say "sit on the floor, with your legs bent and your knees together".

Comment: Squatting = your butt is off the floor. Sitting = your butt is on the floor.

Comment: @mixolydian: yes, and the question specifies that they mean for butts to be on the floor.

Comment: I might actually phrase this as “sit on the floor, with your knees up and your legs together.” What @SamBC describes could be interpreted as *kneeling*- sitting on your heels with bent legs and knees together.

Comment: I don't think any native speaker would take sitting to mean kneeling, but there are indeed many ways to say it.

Comment: @SamBC yes sorry for the confusion- I agree with you wrt sitting vs squatting (and that sitting is what is desired here), just wanted to point out the difference.

Comment: Well, kneeling could be simultaneously either squatting or sitting, depending on whether the person’s butt is up in the air or down on their heels. I guess my point is that with kneeling, the knees are on the ground, and with sitting in some other way, the knees might not be on the ground (they could be pointed up). Maybe it’s unclear what exactly the OP has in mind for where the knees go.

Comment: Thinking about this again, I believe you’re right. “Sitting on the floor” means not sitting on your heels as you might if you were kneeling.